# Sorting on data from language file

Tags: php, codeigniter, sorting

I want to have translations for a number of languages coming from the default Language files (as provided by CI). I'd also like to do some sorting on these values (e.g. to insert them in a dropdown list, I want them to be alphabetically sorted).

I have a project running in CodeIgniter and am in the process of moving all hardcoded text to the language files. This also includes some database tables.

For example, I have the following table:

```
+-------------+---------------------+--------------------+---------------+
| language_id |     language_nl     |    language_en     | language_code |
+-------------+---------------------+--------------------+---------------+
|           1 | Afrikaans           | Afrikaans          | AF            |
|           2 | Albanese            | Albanian           | SQ            |
|           3 | Arabisch            | Arabic             | AR            |
|           4 | Armeens             | Armenian           | HY            |
|           5 | baskisch            | Basque             | EU            |
|           6 | Bengalees           | Bengali            | BN            |
|             |                     |                    |               |
+-------------+---------------------+--------------------+---------------+
```

Now I would like to transfer this table to my language file. 
I will first start by deleting the `language_nl` and `language_en` columns. 
A new column will have to be introduced as well, `language_key`.
So it should look like this:

```
+-------------+--------------+---------------+
| language_id | language_key | language_code |
+-------------+--------------+---------------+
|           1 | language_af  | AF            |
|           2 | language_sq  | SQ            |
|           3 | language_ar  | AR            |
|           4 | language_hy  | HY            |
|           5 | language_eu  | EU            |
|           6 | language_bn  | BN            |
+-------------+--------------+---------------+
```

Then in my language file I will add the following lines:

```
$lang["language_af"] = "African";
$lang["language_sq"] = "Albanian";
$lang["language_ar"] = "Arabic";
```

And so on...

I will then create a manager class to help me in finding the translations for each necessary language for the key. 
It would look something like this:

```
public function getLanguageName($key) {
   return lang(key);
}
```

Now I have two main questions:

1) Is this a good way of approaching the issue I have?

2) Let's say I need the languages to be shown in a drop-down. I want this dropdown to be alphabetically sorted (order will be different based on the language selected, of course). How do I approach this issue? Do I load in all the values from the language file, put them in an array and then sort that array?